# "Mitkommen" oder "mit jdm. kommen"?

Tags: word-choice, verb, preposition

Supposing we have the following sentence:

> I cannot speak yet so good German. That's why I came [here] with an interpreter.

Which of the following senteces would translate it better?

> Ich kann noch nicht sehr gut Deutsch sprechen. Deshalb bin ich mit einem Dolmetscher gekommen.

or

> Ich kann noch nicht sehr gut Deutsch sprechen. Deshalb bin ich einen Dolmetscher mitgekommen.

In other words, should I use the verb *mitkommen*, or just the verb *kommen* and *mit* preposition?

Comment: Please note that the correct spelling is "deshalb" not "deschalb". The "sh" in "deshalb" doesn't represent a "ship"-sound but is more like in "mishap". And don't you want to say "that's _why_ I came..." instead of "that's _because_ I came..."?

Comment: Yes @Chris, you are right. I made the edits. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, there are two verbs that can be used in this situation: **mitkommen** and **mit jemandem kommen**. However, the verb *mitkommen* still needs a preposition. You could say (depending on the situation):

> *Kommen:* Deshalb bin ich **mit** einem Dolmetscher gekommen.

or

> *Mitkommen:* Deshalb bin ich **mit** einem Dolmetscher **mit**gekommen.

The second sentence implies that you came along with the translator. My guess is that it should be actually the other way around: The translator accompanies you, not you him/her. So you could say "Deshalb ist ein Dolmetscher mit mir mitgekommen." The first of the above sentences implies that you both came together.

---

For non-native speakers it is often a bit puzzling that there are situations where you use both the preposition and the prefix. However, for German native speakers this is a natural thing and can be found in various situations:

> Ich will nicht **durch** die Menschenmenge **durch**gehen.
>   Er muss sich **an** der Kasse **an**stellen.
>   Deshalb stellt er sich **an** der Kasse **an**. *(separable verb)*
>   Sie kann schnell **auf** das Pferd **auf**springen.
>   ...

Comment: Ah, you beat me by 28 seconds ;)

Comment: So, if I got it right, it would be more correct to use passive voice here, in order to refer to the translator?

Comment: No, the verb in "deshalb ist er/sie mit mir mitgekommen" is in active voice. "Er/sie ist mitgekommen" is in present perfect (Perfekt). It's the same time/mode/etc. as in "deshalb bin ich mit ihm/ihr mitgekommen". (I only swapped the roles of who came along with whom.)

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct.

The second sentence is wrong grammar. It should be *habe* instead of  *bin* and *mitgenommen* instead of *mitgekommen*.

Comment: but there is also the verb mitkommen. Doesn't it mean "I come with sb or sth"?

Comment: The typos has been fixed. Could you please update your answer? Typos are usually not discussed in answers, except they are the cause of the question. Thanks.